# Formik values not updating in Input form but state updates

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am creating an invoice generator with Formik. The issue is that the Fields Component prints out the new state of the form when I click save changes. But when I return to the form again, the old field persists. If I click on something or return, then the new field replaces the old field. I looked at other solutions like enableReinitialize and passing a handleChange but I have the same issue.

**Edit Invoice Form Component**

```
<Formik
                initialValues={{
                    senderAddress: invoice.senderAddress,
                    clientName: invoice.clientName,
                    clientEmail: invoice.clientEmail,
                    clientAddress: invoice.clientAddress,
                    createdAt: new Date(invoice.createdAt),
                    paymentTerms: invoice.paymentTerms,
                    description: invoice.description,
                    items: invoice.items,
                    invoice: invoice.paymentTerms
                }}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
                onSubmit={onSubmit}
            >
                {formik => (
                    <Form setIsOpen={setIsOpen}
                        enableReinitialize>
                        <Heading>Edit <span>#</span>{invoice.id}</Heading>
                        <Fields client={client} getClientsChild={getClientsChild} setDraftId={setDraftId} />
                        <Buttons>
                            <Button type="button" secondary onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Cancel</Button>
                            <Button type="submit" onClick={() => addDraft(formik.values)}>Save Changes</Button>
                        </Buttons>
                    </Form>
                )}
```

**Fields Component**

```
useEffect(() => {

    console.log(client)
    //setFieldValue(businessID, client.draft.business_id)
    //setFormikContext const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext()
    //setFieldValue(`items[${index}].total`, rounded || '0');
    //onChange={value => setFieldValue(name, value)}
    if (client) {
        console.log("Client in child", client.draft)
        setDraftId(client.draft.id)
        formik.values.businessID = client.draft.businessID
        formik.values.clientName = client.restaurant.first_name + client.restaurant.last_name;
        formik.values.clientEmail = client.restaurant.email;
        formik.values.clientAddress.street = client.restaurant.address;
        formik.values.clientAddress.postCode = client.restaurant.postal_code;
        formik.values.paymentTerms = client.draft.terms;
        formik.values.businessID = client.draft.business_id;
        console.log("Client in child", client.draft)
    }

}, [client])

return (
    <TouchScrollable>
        <Wrapper>
            <FieldSet>
                <Legend>Bill From</Legend>
                <BillFrom>
                    <SelectClient update={update} id="client" label="Select Client" name="clientOptions" options={clients ? clients : [{ name: '', value: '' }]} />
                    <Input label="Street Address" name="senderAddress.street" />
                    <Input label="City" name="senderAddress.city" />
                    <Input label="Post Code" name="senderAddress.postCode" />
                    <Input label="Country" name="senderAddress.country" />
                </BillFrom>
            </FieldSet>

            <FieldSet>
                <Legend>Bill To</Legend>
                <BillTo>
                    <Input label="Business ID ( If financing Net 30 terms )" name="businessID" />
                    <Input label="Client's Name" name="clientName" />
                    <Input label="Client's Email" name="clientEmail" placeholder="e.g. email@example.com" />
                    <Input label="Street Address" name="clientAddress.street" />
                    <Input label="Postal Code" name="clientAddress.postCode" />
                </BillTo>
            </FieldSet>

            <FieldSet>
                <OtherFields>
                    <DatePicker label="Invoice Date" name="createdAt" />
                    <Select label="Payment Terms" name="paymentTerms" options={dropdownOptions} />
                    <Input label="Description" name="description" placeholder="e.g. Graphic Design Service" />
                </OtherFields>
            </FieldSet>

            <Items name="items" />

            {formik.submitCount > 0 && formik.errors &&
                <Errors>
                    {reduceErrors(formik.errors).map((item, index) => (
                        <Error key={index}>{item}</Error>
                    ))}
                </Errors>
            }
        </Wrapper>
    </TouchScrollable>
)
```

}

Comment: Hi @samuel, when you mean _the old field persists_, do you mean the `initialValues` of the form?